# Best test to use for investigating if the difference between means is significant?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, analysis-of-means

I'm studying the length of stay for patients in a hospital. I have a sample of n=4533 observations. Each of these observations are assigned to an admin group numbered between 1 and 8, based on the reason they were admitted to hospital. Admin group 2 has the characteristics:

n = 193,
x̄ = 37.2020725 (days),
s.d. =  35.6247163 (days)

This is the highest mean of the 8 admin groups. I want to test whether the difference between the other groups means and this mean is significant. If I combine the other 7 admin groups, I get the characteristics:

n = 4340,
x̄ = 25.5078341,
s.d. =  31.1011062

I tried to run a t-test to compare these 2 sets of data, but I ended up getting really small values for standard error and degrees of freedom (less than 1). I'm assuming the t-test is inappropriate for this data, perhaps due to the fact that 1 sample size is significantly larger than the other.

Can anyone think of a suitable test to help with what I'm trying to investigate here? Alternatively, should I change my angle and try an ANOVA test (if that is appropriate?), to study whether admin group 2's mean is significantly different from all the other groups' respective means? Hope I made my question clear.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. Note that picking the group with the highest mean and then testing for signicance is questionable (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_dredging). Apart from that, t-test should be a good choice, small p-values and standard errors are normal with large sample sizes.

Comment: Did you really mean the degrees of freedom were less than one? That would almost certainly be an error.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Bayesian equivalent of the t-test. It returns the actual probability that the means are different. You can also use different sample sizes for each distribution.

You can find the paper here:
https://jkkweb.sitehost.iu.edu/BEST/

An online demo can be found here:
http://www.sumsar.net/best_online/

Comment: Returning the probability the the means are different requires assumptions about a so-called "prior" distribution. Changing the prior can have a huge influence on the "posterior" probability that the means are different.

Answer (score 0):

Minitab statistical software will accept summarized data, such as you
provide. **Assuming that data are sufficiently nearly normal and admission groups have nearly equal variances,** the
following output from Minitab for  Welch 2-sample, 2-sided t test might be useful:

```
Two-Sample T-Test and CI 

Sample     N  Mean  StDev  SE Mean
1        193  37.2   35.6      2.6
2       4340  25.5   31.1     0.47

Difference = μ (1) - μ (2)
Estimate for difference:  11.70
95% CI for difference:  (6.56, 16.84)
T-Test of difference = 0 (vs ≠): T-Value = 4.49  P-Value = 0.000  DF = 205
```

Notice that SE Mean for the larger (combined) group is very small.
Thus, in effect, your two-sample test is not much different from a one
sample test on the first group of $H_0: \mu = 25.5$ against
$H_a: \mu \ne 25.5.$ As follows:

```
One-Sample T 

Test of μ = 25.5 vs ≠ 25.5

  N   Mean  StDev  SE Mean      95% CI         T      P
193  37.20  35.62     2.56  (32.14, 42.26)  4.56  0.000
```

@Knarpie is Correct that testing one level of a factor against the
others is controversial. However, one can imagine that there is no
harm in it here. If you had done a one-factor ANOVA comparing all
factors, then is seems that ANOVA would have had a very small P-value,
and your two-sample t test is not much different from looking
*ad hoc* at the 'contrast' that compares one level against the others.
With 8 levels of the factor one might look at as many as ${8\choose 2} = 28$ paired comparisons *ad hoc.* Even the overly conservative Bonferroni
protection against 'false discovery' would consider P-values below 5%
as significant.

If you are writing a formal report, I suggest you begin with an appropriate one-way ANOVA, check to see whether residuals are consistent with normal data and levels have about the same variances,
and (if so) do the appropriate *ad hoc* comparisons. Then report the significant findings that are of practical importance.